# Passing array by ref causes compiler warnings - How to use pointer-arithmetic correct here?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pointer-arithmetic

```
void foo(int **arr)
{
    **arr = 5;     // works fine, no warnings and myArray[0] is 5 after call.
    *(arr+5) = 5;  //warning - assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast - why?
    *(arr)[5] = 5; //No warnig but programm would crash
}   

int main()
{

    int *myArray = (int*)calloc(10,sizeof(int));

    foo(&myArray); //no warning but myArray[5] would be still 0
    foo(myArray);  //warning - passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type (but works fine)

    printf("%d",myArray[5]);

    return 0;
}
```

How to pass the array correctly to my function and access myArray[5] without any warnings?

Answer (score 2):

As written, the proper way to index into `arr` would be

```
(*arr)[5] = 5;
```

Since `arr` is a pointer to a pointer to your array, you don’t want to index into `arr`, you want to index into what `arr` *points to*.  You need to explicitly group the `*` with `arr` since postfix operators like `[]` have higher precedence than unary `*`.

Having said that, the only reason to pass a pointer to `myArray` is if you expect to change the value of `myArray` itself, such as with a call to `realloc`.  If that’s not the intent, then it’s better to write the function as Antti and Peter have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Since `foo` takes a pointer to a pointer to integer, calling `foo(&myArray)` is correct here. But you don't need to do that at all. Simply pass in `myArray` and have `foo` take a pointer to int instead:

```
void foo(int *arr)
{
   arr[5] = 5;
}   

int main()
{
    int *myArray = calloc(10, sizeof(int)); // no need to cast here unless compiling with a C++ compiler

    foo(myArray);

    printf("%d",  myArray[5]); // prints 5

    return 0;
}
```

I know pointers can be confusing, but there seems to be a very fundamental misunderstanding here so I recommend carefully reading the pointer section of any good C textbook again.

Comment: Thank you. I was working on my knowledge of "pointer to pointer" and i asked myself how to work with an array in that context. On a lecture slide was written, that pointer to pointer is used for Call by ref with arrays - so i tried it, and it confused me. Thx for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int *arr) {
    arr[5] = 5;
}   

int main(void) {
    int *myArray = calloc(10, sizeof(int));    
    foo(myArray);    
    printf("%d", myArray[5]);
}
```

You only need to pass the **pointer by reference** if you want to change the value of the original pointer object (i.e. if you want to make the pointer stored in `myArray` point to **another** allocated memory block after calling `foo`).